# Angular 2: Drop down validation issue

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add validation to drop down the problem is with the default value I am selecting :

```
  <select  required name="industryType" id="industryType" [(ngModel)]="institution.industryType" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" class="select-custom">
                <option  selected [value]="default">Select Industry</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Teaching">Teaching</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
              </select>
              </div>
```

while submitting it does not validate the drop down value and without selecting any thing We can navigate,

```
<select  required name="industryType" id="industryType" [(ngModel)]="institution.industryType" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" class="select-custom">
                <option  selected  [value]="null">Select Industry</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Teaching">Teaching</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
              </select>
              </div>
```

With this piece of code by inserting null now it ask to fill this drop down first but the problem is the default selected value on drop down is not showing, it shows an empty field , that is **Select Industry**,

the above snippet shows me the default value i.e **"Select Industry"** but is not validating the drop down we can navigate without selecting it, where as the second snippet is validating the drop down but the default value i.e **Select Industry** is not showing in the drop down

I want the default value to be selected and also the validation check.

can any one suggest me the right solution

Comment: You will need to provide some of your typescript code. Are you checking that the formdata is valid in your code?

Comment: are you getting **Select Industry** as default selected if so, how? when you are using ngModel you will get as empty object

Comment: No i am getting nothing it shows me nothing not even undefiend